# What is a service in springcloud?

Tags: spring-cloud

I'm learning spring cloud. I can see some definition about "microservice", but before that, I have not seen a exact definition about "service".

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the context of Spring Cloud, it is usually akin to microservice. The term does not refer to size, as that's a matter of your system architecture and does not really change anything from the point of view of Spring Cloud's libraries, but usually, the service will be an application in a microservice-based ecosystem that has a certain number of instances. The `name` or `serviceId` of that service is then used to find its instances, usually in Service Discovery.

Comment: You used "sevice" in your answer, I just want to know what it is.

Comment: Usually, an application dedicated to a specific area of business functionality or bounded context. Each service typically has various, often many running instances.